# Как снять битовую маску, с которой приходят данные от браузера по протоколу WebSocket на языке си

Tags: c, веб-программирование, websocket

Не могу понять плгоритм, снятия маски, в которой приходят данные от браузера при использовании протокола WS.

Я нашел вот такой код

```
        masking_key[0] = inbuf[2];
        masking_key[1] = inbuf[3];
        masking_key[2] = inbuf[4];
        masking_key[3] = inbuf[5]; 

        unsigned int i = 6, pl = 0;
        for(; pl < payload_len; i++, pl++)
         {
           payload[pl] = inbuf[i]^masking_key[pl % 4]; 
         }
```

masking_key - массив чаров на 4 элемента, в который записывается 4 байта маски

inbuf - полное сообщение, пришедшее от клиента

payload - массив, подготовленный для записи расшифрованного сообщения

Если конкретней, я не могу понять эту строчку, зачем делать исключающее побитовое или с элеметом по индексу остаток от деления номера текущей итерации на 4 с остатком

```
payload[pl] = inbuf[i]^masking_key[pl % 4];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Маска снимается точно так же как и устанавливается

```
for(int64_t i = 0; i < len; ++i) { 
  data[i] ^= mask[i % 4];
}
```

в этом суть операции xor: (a ^ b ) ^ b = a

#### А для чего это, если коротко, то для того что бы передаваемые данные имели "бинарный" вид.

вот выдержка из стандарта: [RFC 6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#page-29)

> The base framing protocol is formally defined by the following ABNF
> [RFC 5234](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5234).
> It is important to note that the representation of this
> data is binary, not ASCII characters
> ...

так же это связано с безопасностью

> The unpredictability of the masking key is
> essential to prevent authors of malicious applications from selecting
> the bytes that appear on the wire. [RFC 4086](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4086) discusses what
> entails a suitable source of entropy for security-sensitive
> applications...